# Ontouchlistener prevents scrolling

Tags: java, android, scroll, ontouchlistener

I am creating an android app and one of the features is that it allows the user to open up a PDF and automatically starts reading the text out via Text to Speech.

I have given the user an option that if they touch anywhere on the screen it will stop the TTS. The issue is that if I touch the screen to "stop" the TTS; it prevents the user from scrolling since whenever my code detects a touch on the screen it is just trying to perform the action of stopping the TTS rather than scrolling.

Should I not be using onTouchListeners or is there something else that would tackle this issue??

```
pdfView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
            myTTS.stop();
            return true;//always return true to consume event
        }
    });
```

Then inside my XML File:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    tools:context=".pdfViewer">

    <com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
        android:id="@+id/pdf_viewer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView>

</RelativeLayout>
```